# How to get value of textbox in view to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to get the values in textbox at view to controller in asp.net_mvc. without using razor code. i want to get values by c# code. How to I get?

Comment: this would be down to the binding on your model and the textbox. then when a POST occurs, you get the model posted back with the bound values. alternatively you could look at the Request.Forms[] collection and pull it from there but why make life difficult when you can easily get the value bound to the model from the textbox?

Comment: What do you mean by "without using razor code"? Razor "code" allows you to use C# inside your view.

Comment: @Anbu: Hi, did you find any of this helpful?

Answer (score 1):

An easy option is to have a parameter in the controller actionresult that receives the form post that matches the id of the input element you want to post

In your view

```
<input type="text" name="MyField" id="MyField"/>
```

In your controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ReceivePost(string MyField)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply :).

Comment: @Anbu: thanks is preferably expressed by upvoting or marking as answer ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use either the HTML form or the razor form and in post you can use [FormCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.formcollection%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) 
like this

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult myPost(FormCollection myform)
{
// You can access all the elements of the form from that object
}
```

A detailed post on this [blog](http://stack247.wordpress.com/2011/03/20/get-forms-post-values-in-asp-net-mvc-with-formcollection/)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
<input type="text" name="txtname" id="txtname"/>

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Action_name(FormCollection form)
{
 string val=form["txtname"];
 return View();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a html form and name the textboxinput as your method variable:

```
<form action="controllername/actionname">
    <input name="foo" id="foo" type="text"/>
    <input type="submit"/>
 </form>
```

Your mvc controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult actionname(string foo)
{
   //do stuff
}
```

MVC's model binding will bind the named input to the variable of the method. There are alternative ways, like retrieving the FormCollection etc.